# Kernel Panic While installing Ubuntu 12.04 from burnt CD

Tags: dual-boot, boot-partition

I'm having problems installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit on my laptop.

I once had it installed on my laptop with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, but LightDM got weird so I was forced to erase the Ubuntu partition.

I erased all swap partition and ext4 partition. After that, I used MiniTool Partition Wizard to rebuild the MBR.

So there was only Windows 7 left.

After that I tried a VM but I was very disappointed. So I tried installing Ubuntu on my laptop again, but the installer did not recognize my Windows partition. It just showed one HDD with no partition. Just one blank 320 GB drive.

I went back to Windows, did some searching and I messed up my MBR. I used gdisk to wipe MBR along with HDD signature :(

So I couldn't use any partition and my laptop didn't boot into any thing.

So I got Windows 7 install cd and ran recovery. It was fixed in 5 seconds.....

Then I tried installing Ubuntu again with my CD. The kernel panic pictured [here](http://i1356.photobucket.com/albums/q730/stylemate/CAM000721_zps6ffe3317.jpg) occurred:

[image: photograph showing kernel panic]

So I tried installing through `wubi.exe`, but after it was booted, it said it couldn't find root and get root or mount root, and fix partition.

So my question is: How do I successfully install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit on my laptop?
I will gladly add any additional info you need.

Comment: It  may sound a bit far fetched but just for the sake of completeness: Did you check the md5sum of the CD ?